# Re-formatting and editing too large JSON file

Tags: json, large-data, reformatting

I have a very large JSON file (83 MB) with more than 200,000 rows and it has an fundamental error that's no commas between each object because the all of objects not in array and it's look like that:
[image: non-formatted status]

I need a way to edit the hole of rows in the file (not manually) because current status of the file hinders the process of parsing, and i want it to be like that:
[image: formatted status]

Comment: have you looked at using sed or similiar command-line editor tool?

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Turning it into a valid array consists of adding a comma at the end of each line except the last, and wrapping in square brackets. I'd use sed/awk/etc, although I'd  probably just stick the brackets in manually.

Comment: no, i am a windows user :(

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options like you can split the file online using online file splitter. And then you can use VScode to format it.

Or else you can use https://www.json-buddy.com/json-editor-download.htm

This tool to open large json file and format as you want.